# How to use vlookup to find the value based on time in another table (google sheet)?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, vlookup

[image]

I'm trying to get the values for column C in Table 1 from column H by using `vlookup`. However, seems like the `vlookup` doesn't work and return a `N/A`. I had checked both `ISDATE` and `ISNUMBER` for data in column B and column G, they are the same.

One of the possible reason I can think of is because I'm using `query function` to get the data for column F and column G from Table 1. However, I'm not sure how to solve this so that I can use the `vlookup` function or any other method so that I can match the value based on the time.

I attached the google sheet link below in case you need it:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17coke3-oyDRLHgz79PDl3KX68kFOEte-aynVe-xEITU/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added a new sheet ("Erik Help") with the following formula solution in C2:

`=ArrayFormula({"Value";IF(B3:B="",,VLOOKUP(ROUND(B3:B,10),ROUND(G3:H,10),2,FALSE))})`

This single formula returns all results for the column.

You were experiencing the effects of floating decimals, meaning numbers generated in different ways are actually different in memory to very fine degrees. I just used ROUND(...,10) on everything to limit that, and it works fine.

Comment: Thanks Erik, may I know round off to 10 decimal places will be 100% work for all the time?

Comment: In theory, yes. The only way to tell you that it will definitely work 100% of the time would be if it were tested against every single second of every hour of 24 hours... which no one will do. But, yes, 10 is a safe number. If my solution does, in fact, meet your posted need, please take a moment to mark it as "Best Answer." This lets other volunteers know that the issue has been resolved, as well as making it easy for future sight visitors to find the most relevant answers to their similar questions.